How to add object values from an array of multiple objects into an array readable for ngFor?
I get an array like this:
obj_Array = [{"Information":{ID: 1, Name: "Frank"}},"Route":{Direction: "north", Time: 10:50:24},"Music":{volume: "loud", input: "3.5mm"}];

I need to take the object values from Information, Route, and Music: 1, Frank, north, 10:50:24 etc... And save them into an array that is readable for Angular front-end ngFor. So I can print the values to the screen using Angular Material Table.
Currently says the array is an object and cannot iterate through it. But when I do .isArray() it prints true.
I want an end product like the below Array:
String_Array = ["1","Frank","north","10:50:24","loud","3.5mm"];

This now should be easily read by ngFor for it to be displayed.

When in doubt for loop it out:


const objects = [
    {"Information": {ID: 1, Name: "Frank"}},
    {"Route": {Direction: "north", Time: "10:50:24"}},
    {"Music": {volume: "loud", input: "3.5mm"}}
];
let strings = [];
objects.forEach(item => {
    Object.values(item).forEach(innerObj => {
        Object.values(innerObj).forEach(value => {
            strings.push(String(value));
        });
    });
});
console.log(strings);




I will have to give this a shot - Will update after. Thank you!



const obj = [
    {"Information": {ID: 1, Name: "Frank"}},
    {"Route": {Direction: "north", Time: "10:50:24"}},
    {"Music": {volume: "loud", input: "3.5mm"}}
];
var allvals = [];
for(let i=0;i<=obj.length-1;i++){
   Object.values(obj[i]).forEach(val => {
       allvals.push(Object.values(val))
      
   })
}
 console.log(allvals.flat())



// we can do it

A material table generally show an array of objects, not an array of strings. Well, really you can display an array of string in the way
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <!--you use element[0], element[1], element[2]... -->
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[0]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

But...  how about?
  arrayDisplay=obj_Array.map((x:any)=>
       ({...x.Information,...x.Route,...x.Music}))

This return an array of object in the way
   [{ID: 1, Name: "Frank",Direction: "north", 
     Time: "10:50:24",volume: "loud", input: "3.5mm"}]

And you use the "clasic"
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ID}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="NAme">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  ...

NOTE: the array_obj in the question is bad formatted
